# How to completely skip unit tests and integration tests during maven release prepare and perform with maven release plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have set up some automation to perform maven semantic versioining using maven release plugin. As such i am using the below :-

```html
mvn -B clean release:clean -DpreparationGoals=clean release:prepare -Darguments="-DskipTests" -Darguments="-DskipITs" -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true" release:perform -Dusername=$GIT_USERNAME -Dpassword=$GIT_PASSWORD
```

Everything works great except for the fact that during perform phase, i still see the TESTS being executed in our jenkins logs.
I am wondering what would be the best way to skip any kind of tests during this maven release prepare and perform without having to make any changes in existing pom.xml as i would like to enforce that through maven arguments passed as CLI arguments so that we don't have to update 1000 of poms using this automation
Any help or suggestions here would be greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments) property to do this.  Quoting can be very important.

Example:

```
mvn release:prepare ... -Darguments="-Dmaven.test.skip=true -DsomethingElse=whatever"
```

Here, I pass the [`maven.test.skip`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip) property (defined by the [`maven-surefire-plugin`'s `test` goal](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)) through to the execution of `mvn` run by the `prepare` goal of the `maven-release-plugin`.

Comment: Thanks Laird. so if i have to skip the tests and both unit and integration under both prepare and perform phase, should i simply use the below:-
mvn -B clean release:clean -DpreparationGoals=clean release:prepare -Darguments="-Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipITs" release:perform

Comment: (For the record and those coming after you: I STRONGLY advise against disabling tests. I am also commenting only on the `arguments` portion of the command line.) Yes, I think that's right for your use case. Note that `maven.test.skip` is documented to exclude test compilation as well.